# App.get_running_app().root.my_method() - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'my_method()

Tags: python, kivy, dashboard

I try to call a function on my Screenmanager after a button was pressed. But the call to (App.get_running_app().root.) does not get me an object.

## The Buttons will not work for me and i do not know why.

There seems to be an issue that i do not have a root object, but why. It worked before i tried it with the dashboard.

I have tried including methods from the ScreenManager Class which i could not call 
and call methods out of the Dashboard class, which function.

python file:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
class DashboardScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DashboardScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Initialize Target Container
        App.get_running_app().root.get_character_selection_screen()


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(DashboardScreen(name='dashboard'))

    def get_character_selection_screen(self):
        pass


class MatrixApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MatrixApp().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
<DashboardScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "test"
```

Error Message
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
    'get_character_selection_screen'

Indentation might be messed up, because i tried to upload it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to schedule it with clock, so you are sure the app and widgets are ready

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock

class DashboardScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DashboardScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.after_init)

    def after_init(self, dt):
        App.get_running_app().root.get_character_selection_screen()
```

Comment: You are a genius, thank you so much, that was really helping me out. I would have never guessed this.

Comment: @nebelherr No problem. Maybe you can accept the answer unless you need something else.

Comment: @Nebelherr :D you will figure it our some day

Comment: Sorry, that was quite obvious. Now i see it.